# Place "Title" text into CSS

Tags: html, css, duplicates

I have an HTML diary page and I would like to remove lots of duplicated TITLE text from the HTML and place it in a few lines in CSS. So that when the mouse hovers over an item the title text would re-appear. Is this possible?
My HTML looks like:-

```
<td class="Provisional-Saturday" title="Provisionally Booked (NO deposit)">11</td>
<td class="Provisional-Sunday" title="Provisionally Booked (NO deposit)" >12</td>
<td class="Covid-19-Break" title="Safety day - left empty">13</td>
<td class="Covid-19-Break" title="Safety day - left empty">14</td>
<td class="Available-weekday" title="Not Booked">15</td>
<td class="Available-weekday" title="Not Booked">16</td>
<td class="Available-weekday" title="Not Booked">17</td>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
class^="Available":after, class^="Booked":after, class^="Provisional":after {
padding: 2px;
display:none;
position: relative;
top: -2px;
right: -3px;
width: 50px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #fef4c5;
border: 1px solid #d4b943;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-ms-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
class^="Available":hover:after, class^="Booked":hover:after, class^="Provisional":hover:after{
    display: block;
}
class^="Available" label:after{
    content: "Not Booked";
}
class^="Booked" label:after{
    content: "Booked & Deposit paid";
}
class^="Provisional" label:after{
    content: "Booked & Deposit paid";
}
class^="Covid" label:after{
    content: "Safety day - left empty";
}
```

Is this possible, or am I chasing my tail?
Thanks for any help or guidance offered.

Comment: Consider how this will look to a screen-reader: completely invisible because (for the most part) CSS is meaningless to a blind user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CSS is only presentation language so we can't add titles to HTML elements, but we can use its pseudo classes to add content or tool tips which are purely CSS. 
So I have modified you HTML to the following:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td class="list-item Available">11</td>
        <td class="list-item Booked" >12</td>
        <td class="list-item Provisional">13</td>
        <td class="list-item Available">14</td>
        <td class="list-item Booked">15</td>
        <td class="list-item Provisional">16</td>
        <td class="list-item Covid">17</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

and you can use the following css to show and hide those tool tips

```
.list-item{
        position:relative;
        padding:5px;
    }
   .list-item:after {
        content:"";
        margin: 2px;
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 30px;
        z-index:1;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #fef4c5;
        border: 1px solid #d4b943;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -ms-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .list-item:hover:after{
        display: block;
    }
    .list-item:after:hover{
        display:none;
    }
    .Available:after{
        content: "Not Booked";
    }
    .Booked:after{
        content: "Booked & Deposit paid";
    }
    .Provisional:after{
        content: "Booked & Deposit paid";
    }
    .Covid:after{
        content: "Safety day - left empty";
    }
```

notice that I have used a common class .list-item to style all the pseudo classes so you can alter the position and styling of toot tip from this only, and then the specific classes to show the respective content related to them on hover.

Hope this helps !

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have deleted my code and implemented your code above, and modified my html as suggested. Unfortunately, with the same result as my attempt - nothing happens or can be seen.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying my code, but I checked it again and its working. So can you make a jsfiddle to replicate the issue you are facing and share the link here, so that I can check what is causing the issue, meanwhile you can check the fiddle with my code here and it shows the css tooltip when <td> is hovered.
https://jsfiddle.net/3qfLywo5/1/

Comment: Hi Gagandeep, Thanks for your help. I've tried your jsfiddle and it is just what I wanted. Can I provide the link to my website for you to see what I am doing? I tried in an answer post but it was ruled "OFF-SIDE" and I had to remove it.

Comment: Hey Buddhabaker, sure just give me the link to the webpage containing this html markup, I'd be more than happy to help!

Comment: https://www.nineoaks-fisheries.co.uk/bookingscalendar/2020/availabilitysummary.shtml Click on July and the first two rows (july dates 1-10) contain your changes and  the css is in https://www.nineoaks-fisheries.co.uk/assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css lines 1293+

Comment: HI Gagandeep. I forgot to mention in my previous comment that I am using Chrome and Edge gives different results?

Comment: Thanks for the details, I will check and let you know.

Comment: Hey I checked you website and it is working fine as it should, the only issue is when you hover over the dates to right ex: 10th then the tool tip starts to hide inside the table as the `overflow` of its parent table is set to `hidden` . To solve that just set the `overflow` to `visible` for `table .cal` selector on line 941 of mbr-additional.css file.
Also I checked the code on firefox, mozilla and internet explorer and its working fine for me.

Comment: Hi Gagandeep; I have made a few minor changes my end but otherwise updated as you suggest. It works great on Edge, Explorer, Opera, Firefox and fine too on Chrome Canary. But for me Google Chrome does not show the tooltips. But, hey you can't have everything, Chrome users will just have to do without them. Very many thanks for your invaluable help. I just wish I had you inner knowledge.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked for you. I am more then happy to help and so kind of you to appreciate it. If you find the answer suitable can you mark it as solved so that the question can be closed, Thank you.

Comment: if you feel that a answer has solved your query in question you asked, then just Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of that answer. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".